# Just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and my USB mouse & Keyboard won't work

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, mouse

I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 from a live CD and I wasn't able to get it to recognize either my keyboard (C.Y.B.O.R.G V5) or my mouse (R.A.T 7).  I eventually gave up but later on I was able to use an old keyboard that uses a serial port instead of a USB (which works).  I was then able to install the OS but my mouse still won't work.  I am unable to navigate with just the keyboard so I really don't know what to do.

Comment: serial port or PS/2? Also, would you happen to have your keyboard/mouse on a USB 3.0 port? that causes trouble

Comment: The keyboard is in a serial port and the mouse is connected to a USB 2.0.

Comment: I've never seen a serial port keyboard ever on a PC. Keyboards went from 8 pin mini din to pc/2

Comment: Ok well the keyboard works just fine it's the mouse that won't work.

Comment: Try to go through this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection if that doesn't help post the information you've collected during the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Boot into BIOS configuration page and search for

[**USB Legacy Support**](http://www.linuxusbdownload.com/images/Bilder/AMI_6.gif) and enable it.

Then try again with the Usb keyboard and mouse.